# Android socketfailed:eaccess(Permission Denied)

Tags: android, mysql, permissions, socketexception

I'm using java and PHP trying to make a connection with PHP MySQL(xampp) . trying to save from my register form to my database . but keep getting this socket failed: access error when I click the "register" button. have been searching for other threads . still no good . I'm debugging my apps to my Lenovo API 22, not through virtual devices.  what am I missing? is it the IP ? I've tried to change my phone IP too , still no good. pls help

Here's my Login class

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText username, password;
String Username, Password;
Context ctx = this;
String NAME = null, ADDRESS= null, MOBILE_NUMBER = null,USERNAME = null, PASSWORD = null, EMAIL = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
    //mEmailView.setPaintFlags(mEmailView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    //mPasswordView.setPaintFlags(mPasswordView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)


}

 public void login_register(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
}

public void login_signin(View v) {
    Username = username.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();
    BackGround b = new BackGround();
    b.execute(Username, Password);
}

class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**Button btn_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
     btn_register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
    }); */

    /** Button btn_signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signin);
     btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //buttonnya dsni tapi aksinya dibawah
    /** attemptLogin();
    }
    }); */

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String username = params[0];
    String password = params[1];
    String data = "";
    int tmp;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/MYCODE/konserfutsal/login.php");
        String urlParams = "username="+username+"&password="+password;

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        while ((tmp = is.read()) != -1) {
            data += (char) tmp;
        }

        is.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return data;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    }
}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (String s){
        String err = null;
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");
            NAME = user_data.getString("name");
            EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");
            ADDRESS = user_data.getString("address");
            MOBILE_NUMBER = user_data.getString("mobile_number");
            USERNAME = user_data.getString("username");
            PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MenuActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name", NAME);
        i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
        i.putExtra("address", ADDRESS);
        i.putExtra("mobile_number", MOBILE_NUMBER);
        i.putExtra("username", USERNAME);
        i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
        i.putExtra("err", err);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
}
```

And here's my register class

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name, password, username, email, mobile_number, address;
String Name, Password, Username, Email, Mobile_number, Address;
Button btn_back;
Context ctx=this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_name);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_address);
    mobile_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_mobile_number);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_pass);

    btn_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_btn_back);
    btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    }

public void register_register (View V){
        Name = name.getText().toString();
        Email = email.getText().toString();
        Address = address.getText().toString();
        Mobile_number = mobile_number.getText().toString();
        Username = username.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
        Background b = new Background();
        b.execute(Name, Email, Address, Mobile_number, Username, Password);
    }
 class Background extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String email = params[1];
            String address = params[2];
            String mobile_number = params[3];
            String username = params[4];
            String password = params[5];
            String data="";
            int tmp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/MYCODE/konserfutsal/register.php");
                String urlParams = "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&address="+address+"&mobile_number="+mobile_number+"&username="+username+"&password="+password;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                    data+= (char)tmp;
                }
                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return data;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if(s.equals("")){
            s="Data saved successfully.";
        }
        Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
}
```

and this's what i add on my manifest.xml above the  tag coz the other threads tell this

```
<uses_permission android:name="android.permission.INETERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

and here's my init.php

```
<?php

 error_reporting(0);
 $db_name = "konserfutsal";
 $mysql_user = "root";
 $mysql_pass = "";
 $server_name = "localhost";

 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);

 if(!$con){
 echo '{"message":"Unable to connect to the database."}';
 }

?>


error_reporting(0);

$db_name = "konserfutsal";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$server_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);

if(!$con){
    echo '{"message":"Unable to connect to the database."}';
}

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 require "init.php";

 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];

//$name = "sdf";
//$password = "sdf";

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `username`='".$username."' AND  `password`='".$password."';";

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 $response = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $response =  array("id"=>$row[0],"name"=>$row[1],"email"=>$row[2],"address"=>$row[3],"mobile_number"=>$row[4],"username"=>$row[5],"password"=>$row[6]);
}

 echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response));

?>
```

register.php

```
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 require "init.php";

 $name = $_POST["name"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $address = $_POST["address"];
 $mobile_number = $_POST["mobile_number"];
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];

 //$name = "sdf";
 //$password = "sdf";
 //$email = "sdf@r54";

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `user_info` (`id`,`name`,`email`,`address`,`mobile_number`,`username`,`password`) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$email."', '".$address."', '".$mobile_number."', '".$username."', '".$password."');";
 if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
     echo '{"message":"Unable to save the data to the database."}';
}

?>
```

tbh, I'm learning this code from someone's youtube for "adding the connection from my android to mysql". but I already adjust it with my code . pls help me . my final exam needs to be collected by tonight T^T . let me know if u want to see my XML too.

Comment: `trying to make connection with mysql .`. Dont think so. `"http://10.0.2.2/MYCODE/konserfutsal/login.php"`. Your android app tries to 'connect' with a php script.

Comment: ya , i mean , im using java and php trying to connect to mysql , i have my login.php , register.php and init.php aswell . can it be some help ?

Comment: Is it re!evant for the problem  that php tries to connect to mysql? I think that your Android app cannot connect to the webserver to begin with. So the call does not even reach the php script. What do you think?

Comment: i've added the php above,pls help checking . i dont think the problem comes from the php . in my phpmyadmin , im using "konsertuftsal" db with "user_info" table in it . i used "user_data" as i declared on my android apps and have called this "user_data" in my android app  from php and convert it to "user_info" in my php ? am i wrong ?

Comment: Why are you posting php script and only talk about php when i just ecplained you that the php script is not even invoked but your Android app has troubles to connect with the webserver? Your reaction does not make sense. You should have elaborated about the connection problem and indicated the statement that produces the error.

Comment: im sorry good sir , i dont really understand what ure talking about . what's this "webserver" that you mean ? pls kindly explain . im really new in android apps . i dont think im using any "webserver" except the localhost/phpmyadmin . is it consider as webserver ?

Comment: did you mean my php script doesnt even called in my apps ?

Comment: I repeat: If your app cannot connect to the webserver than your script will not be called by the webserver of course. So concentrate on the connection problem if indeed your Android app cannot connect.

Comment: `"http://10.0.2.2`. The webserver socket runs on device with ip 10.0.2.2. You can only use 10.0.2.2 if the app runs on an emulator and the webserver runs on the same pc as the emulator runs on. Phpmyadminn is no webserver.  Can it be that you use Apache as webserver? `im really new in android apps`. That does not matter as i was talking about a webserver and a php interpreter.

Comment: my device IP Address looks like this 
   [fe80::9a0c:a5ff:fe89:b873] 

    192.168.100.3

    ::1

i've tried change it to 192.168.100.3 still no good . 
And yes im using apache as webserver ( since it's xampp )

Comment: `my device IP Address`Do you mean your Android device? That address is irrelevant. The client app should use the ip of the computer where the webserver is running on. It will be something like 192.168.100..... if the computer is in the same (W)LAN which it should.

Comment: ok , ive just try making a new project , with different coding of login , it works when i used my computer ip v4 address . that 192.168.100.6 now i believe the only problem is on the coding . i really cant find the problem on my coding .

Comment: If you do not tell what the problem is then how could we?

Comment: ahh . the problem now is , when i click on the "register" button on the "register.class" it said "Unable to save the data to the database" << same as what i write on the register.php . it means it has been connected to the php now , right ? then, the problem is i still cant register .-.

Comment: Well why cant it save to the database? You have to find out. Why does it go wrong? Did you check if all the values were received right? No. You did not. You should start checking if all post psrameters come in. Echo them too to see.